# Why am i getting error in compiling c file in linux os?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I am new to linux environment and i am trying to compile c file in linux OS but i'm getting so many errors. I searched on internet but didn't get any solution.
here is my file "first.c" :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("Hello world");
 return 0;
}
```

error i am getting :

```
┌──(dj㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/c]
└─$ gcc -o output first.c
In file included from /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/crtdefs.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/conio.h:9,
                 from first.c:1:
/usr/local/include/_mingw.h:272:2: error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!
  272 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/crtdefs.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/conio.h:9,
                 from first.c:1:
/usr/local/include/_mingw.h:580:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__debugbreak’
  580 | void __cdecl __debugbreak(void);
```

These are only few lines of errors i am getting. there are numerous lines of errors i am getting.I'm using linux terminal to compile the file. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what enviroment are you actual compiling? Because `_mingw.h` seams to be a windows only header. So if you compile for Linux it should not be included. And yeah you yourself do not include it, I see that. There is probably something wrong with the `stdio.h` that gets included or default includes. But I'm no windows expert. Do you compile in this new WSL (Linux subsystem for Windows)?

Comment: What does `gcc -H -c first.c` output? The `-H` option prints the paths of all the header files that get included.

Comment: Do the commands `echo $CPATH` and `echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH` output anything other than blank lines?

Comment: How have you installed `gcc`?

Comment: Something makes me wonder if your first line really is including `stdio.h` or maybe `conio.h`?

Comment: gcc -H -c first.c   
. /usr/local/include/conio.h
.. /usr/local/include/crtdefs.h
... /usr/local/include/corecrt.h
.... /usr/local/include/_mingw.h
..... /usr/local/include/_mingw_mac.h
..... /usr/local/include/_mingw_secapi.h
In file included from /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/crtdefs.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/conio.h:9,
                 from first.c:1:
echo $CPATH and echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH commands are giving blank output

Comment: You have installed a wrong gcc and/or the standard library. The fact that it is all in `/usr/local/` suggests that you have installed it from source. Don't do that unless you know exactly what you are doing. Remove `/usr/local/include` and try again.